# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, datetime, time, typeerror

I'm trying to compare two datetime.time values but I get this error:

> File "c:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\pyfiche\code.py", line 33, in timeofweek
> if (a.time >= d0.time() and a.time() <= d6.time()) or (a.time() >= d21.time() and a.time() <= d23.time()):
> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.time'

and this is my code:

```
def timeofweek(a):
    d6 = a.replace(hour=6, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) 
    d21 = a.replace(hour=21, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) 
    d0 = a.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) 
    d23 = a.replace(hour=23, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) 
    if a.weekday() in range(0,6):
        print(a.time(),type(a.time())) #for debugging and they are both Datetime.time
        print(d0.time(),type(d0.time())) #for debugging and they are both Datetime.time
        if (a.time() >= d6.time() and a.time() < d21.time()):
            return 1
        if (a.time() >= d0.time() and a.time() < d6.time()) or (a.time() >= d21.time() and a.time() <= d23.time()):
            return 2
    if a.weekday() == 6:
        if (a.time() >= d6.time() and a.time() <= d21.time()):
            return 2
        if (a.time >= d0.time() and a.time() <= d6.time()) or (a.time() >= d21.time() and a.time() <= d23.time()):
            return 3
```

I'm sure that d6, d21, d0, d23 are all the same type Datetime.time

the problem started when the input value changed from 24h to 12h format, but still when I print the value for debugging I still get the 24h format everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't calling the .time() method for a in the second to last row. (You're missing brackets)